# Articles Books on Automated Writing Evaluation Techniques

Tags: computational-linguistics

I have long been out of the NLP game, but I am curious to get back in.  I wanted to know about modern techniques for doing automated writing evaluation of English texts.  I want to take essay-form content from non-native speakers and write an application to assess how well-written it is.

I left the question vague on purpose, because I really want to read up on the topic and it has been a while.  Does anyone have any pointers to good books or articles on this domain?

Comment: Well-written-ness doesn't really come under the purview of linguistics, but your overall question does come under NLP or at least CS. I wonder if it's within our scope. You could probably ask this question on StackOverflow too where NLP and CS are also on-topic.

Comment: I thought it would be a better fir here because I am interested in the literature, NLP and general linguistics.

Comment: Well linguistics doesn't deal with "how well-written" something is. That's the purvue of English teachers (or whatever language), style guides, literary criticism, etc. Linguistics is the scientific study of natural human language as it is used.